# Typescript 'Failed to Compile` Errors as Warnings

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I've created an app with `npx create-react-app my-app --typescript` and I would like to configure it so that my app will still compile despite typescript errors so that I can return to them when I'm ready.

I do not see any `compilerOptions` for this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 10):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    strict: false
  }
)
```

Admittedly a Typescript noob but this took me forever to figure out. CRA defaults strict to true which will fail the compilation for a wide range of errors. This is extremely implicit and it looks like setting this to true does quite a few other things as well:

`enables --noImplicitAny, --noImplicitThis, --alwaysStrict, --strictBindCallApply, --strictNullChecks, --strictFunctionTypes and --strictPropertyInitialization.`

There are other errors I'm still getting a failed compilation for ie:

`Property 'property' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

I can get around it without much hassle and maybe I'm not using Typescript the way it is meant to be used but all I want is to see the warnings in my IDE so I can return to them when I'm ready after I at least have some proof of concept. Drove me a little crazy to the point where I was considering restarting without TS even though I really like it and have benefited from using it.

I think there should be something on the [tsconfig docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) with at least a brief summary of the implications from this `strict` option, but I digress.

Comment: +1 the suggestion to update their documentation. Incidentally, the Typescript docs are open-source, so you could make a pull request to that effect.