# Create react app doesn't compile on typescript error

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I want typescript errors to appear as warnings, but not crash my dev server. I was able to do so for eslint with setting `.env` file with `ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true`.

Is there a typescript equivalent?

It's really counter-productive for the prototyping phase.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014387/typescript-failed-to-compile-errors-as-warnings) suggests:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    strict: false
  }
)
```

But this also configures many other things (i.e. no no implicit any)

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript 'Failed to Compile\` Errors as Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014387/typescript-failed-to-compile-errors-as-warnings)

Comment: No it doesn't, edited the question to reflect that, thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the enviroment variable `TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true`.

## More

You can find this and other options here : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

**Note:** As of 2022-02-20 this is not only for development, but also for production.